# Need some hint to prove following is a sigma algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am doing Probability measures by myself and having problems proving the following
Suppose that $\Omega$ is the sample space and $\Omega'\subseteq\Omega$ then we have to prove that if $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ then
$F'=\{A\cap\Omega'\mid A\in F\}$ is also a $\sigma$-algebra.

I know that $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ are in $F'$ but I am having a problem in proving that if $B\in F'$ then $B^c\in F'$ and if $B_1,B_2,\dots\in F'$ then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i\in F'.$

My try is if I choose $B\in F'$ then $B=A\cup\Omega'$ for some $A\in F$ then complement of $B$ that is
$B^c=A^c\cup \Omega'^{c}$ now how do I show that this is also in $F'$? If anyone gives some hint for this that will be a great help.Thanks.

Comment: $\Omega$ is not in $F'.$ $\Omega'\in F'.$

Comment: Do you mean $B^c\in F'?$

Comment: yes ,If I choose $B\in F'$ then we have to show that $B^c\in F'$

Comment: But you wrote $A^c.$

Comment: If I choose $B\in F'$ then $B=A\cap\Omega'$ then $B^c=A^c\cup\Omega'^c$

Comment: Note that you are trying to prove that $F'$ is a $\sigma-$algebra for $\Omega'.$ $F'$ is not a $\sigma-$algebra for $\Omega.$ So it is worth being clear that you need $B^c\in F'$ where $B^c=\Omega'\setminus B.$ It is not true that $\Omega\setminus B\in F'.$

Comment: So you need to prove: $\Omega'\setminus (A\cap \Omega')=(\Omega\setminus A)\cap \Omega'.$ This is true in general, if $A,B\subseteq C,$ then $B\setminus (A\cap B)=(C\setminus A)\cap B.$

Comment: Basically, the notation $S^c$ is very dangerous, because it is not a function just of $S$ but of the universe of which $S$ is part. As in this question, there are two universes, $\Omega$ and $\Omega',$ so using $S^c$ is ambiguous.

Comment: It is better to use $U\setminus A$ for the complement, when $U$ is the universe. The set minus character can be gotten with `\setminus`.

Comment: Take a look at the De Morgan's Laws

Answer (score 1):

The $S^c$ notation for complement is somewhat dangerous, because it is hiding another argument, the universe. It is usually better to be explicit, and write $U\setminus S$ for the complement of $S$ inside the universal set $U.$

In this question, the reason this is important is that we are trying to prove that $F'$ is a $\sigma-$algebra for the set $\Omega',$ not for the set $\Omega.$  This means that we need to use the complement on $\Omega',$ not the complement in $\Omega.$

So the complement condition you want is if $B\in F'$ then $\Omega'\setminus B\in F'.$

This is not the same as saying $\Omega\setminus B\in F',$ which would not be true for any $B\in F'$ if $\Omega'\neq \Omega.$

Prove the following lemma:

> If $C\subseteq U$ and $D$ is any set, then $C\setminus D=C\setminus (C\cap D)=C\cap (U\setminus D).$

Then in your case, if $B=\Omega'\cap A$ you set $U=\Omega, C=\Omega', D=A.$ This gets you that if $A\in F,$ then $\Omega\setminus A\in F,$ and thus $\Omega'\setminus B\in F'.$